# How to specify path for file from different project in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, path

I've got two projects in WPF and one project is the main one and the second one is just for testing (it uses files of the main project - files are added via Project -> add -> Existing items... -> selected file -> add as link so that the file is only in the main project really).

Folders with projects are these:

```
C:\Work\...\Projects\Main
C:\Work\...\Projects\XXXTestProject
```

where XXX stands for different parts of the Main project which I test separately.

I've got the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Sokoban.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sokoban"
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="Window1" Height="559" Width="419">
    <Window.Resources>        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="GameDesk.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>        
        <Rectangle local:GameDeskProperties.FieldSize="30" Name="myrect" Style="{DynamicResource GameDesk}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

... which should use XAML resources from GameDesk.xaml which is in the main project and it seems that I can't use Pack URI (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). How can I specify the file?

- Should I use absolute path? (C:\Work...\Main\Resources\GameDesk.xaml)
- Or is there any other way?

Thank you for help!

Comment: So you've added *GameDesk.xaml* to your test project as a linked file?

Comment: Yes. Every important part of test project should be from main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Use a pack:// URI of the form:

pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml

if the XAML is in a referenced assembly

or

pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Subfolder/SiteOfOriginFile.xaml

if the XAML is loose and copied to the bin folder.

Comment: I want to use the first option but I don't think it can work in my case because I don't have these two projects under one solution. Both projects are in separated solution. How would it exactly look like in my scenario? Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't have to be in the same solution, just add a reference to the DLL.

Comment: But if it has to be compiled ("reference to the DLL") than I can't make changes in test project (which effectively means in main project). So far I've set the pre-build event in VS which copies the needed file which is not a nice solution but it works and copy is done via relative paths so that it remains portable.

Comment: You can add a reference to a DLL in your bin or add a reference path. - This is not a problem and not WPF related - just a common .NET reference path issue that is solvable.

Comment: If you do the reference correctly, When the DLL is updated the reference is updated.

Comment: In the project options add a reference path, it is saved in the projectname.username.csproj.user file, copy the XML to the projectname.csproj file and the you can edit the XML to add parameters e.g. $(Platform), $(Configuration) and even set copylocal=true and remove the build event (just make sure the specificversion=false).